# Вывод из MySQL элемент массива в переменную

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код счетчика переходов по внешней ссылке. Как в переменную $url вывести элемент из массива (урл), обведенный красным на картинке, чтобы сделать редирект на этот урл?

```html
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()) ;
if (empty($_GET['id'])) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found');
        die();
    } else {
 $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        mysql_query("update lbsplash set click = click + 1 where id = '$id'");
 
        //$url = выбрать из массива элемент 'product url', где id='$id'
        header('Location: '.$url);
 }
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("select data from lbsplash where id ='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$json_data = $row['data'];
$data = json_decode($json_data, true);
$url = $data['product'];
```